# How to combine similar values in a comma separated string in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string with values :

```
var string = 1-1, 1-2, 2-8, 2-10, 3-13, 3-14, 3-15,
```

now i want to combine them as follow:

```
var result = 1-1,2| 2-8,10|  3-13,14,15
```

How to achieve this in JQuery or Javascript.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/ritunilapo/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way purely in Jquery or Javascipt, with out ES or ECMA scripts

Comment: https://jsbin.com/mobuvuquza/2/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var string = "1-1, 1-2, 2-8, 2-10, 3-13, 3-14, 3-15";

var result_array = [];
string.split(",").forEach(function (item) {
  var first_number = item.trim().split("-")[0];
  var second_number = item.trim().split("-")[1];

  if (!result_array[first_number]) {
    result_array[first_number] = [];
  }

  result_array[first_number].push(second_number);
});

var ordered_result = [];
result_array.forEach(function (content, index) {
  ordered_result.push(index + "-" + content.join(","));
});

var result = ordered_result.join("| ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there a way purely in Jquery or Javascipt, with out ES or ECMA scripts